# Bootstrap Carousel Image Slider unable to slide in React

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import img1 from "./images/img1.jpg";
import img2 from "./images/img2.jpg";
import img3 from "./images/img3.jpg";

class Slider extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly"
        className="carousel slide"
        data-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div className="carousel-inner">
          <div className="carousel-item active">
            <img src={img1} className="d-block w-100" alt="First Slide" />
          </div>
          <div className="carousel-item">
            <img src={img2} className="d-block w-100" alt="Second Slide" />
          </div>
          <div className="carousel-item">
            <img src={img3} className="d-block w-100" alt="Third Slide" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Slider;
```

I am trying to develop 'Image Slider' using Carousel component of bootstrap (version 6.13.4) in React. My Slider is just loading first image. It is not sliding to next images. Above is my Slider Component. Please Help me to understand what is going wrong here?

Comment: Give that Bootstrap 4.5 only came out recently, your version number is definitely suspect.   Why wouldn't you be using one of the react-ified versions of Bootstrap like react-bootstrap or reactstrap?

Comment: It is bootstrap 4.5.0. Mistakenly I checked the version using command 'npm -v bootstrap'. It showed 6.13.4.

Comment: Did you included all the proper files in index.html?

Comment: I have imported "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" in index.js file. What else we need to do?

Comment: You need to include popper and bootstrap JS files either in index or as a part of import/require in react. Popper and other javascript bits is what makes the slider work. Read the getting started at Bootstrap again:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/